# Help with simplifying implicit differentiation

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Given the equation

$\frac{y}{x+7y} = x^6 + 7$,  find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Ok, so I started to solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and got to here:

$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}(x+7y)-(1+7\frac{dy}{dx})(y)}{(x+7y)^2} = 6x^5$.

This is where I'm stuck. Do I distribute the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ ? But then that would be messy, wouldn't it. Any help is will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did until now is correct, good job. Now, we isolate $\frac{dy}{dx}$, like solving a first degree equation:

$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}(x+7y)-(1+7\frac{dy}{dx})(y)}{(x+7y)^2} = 6x^5 \implies  \frac{dy}{dx}(x+7y)-(1+7\frac{dy}{dx})(y) = 6x^5(x+7y)^2 $$

Factoring $\frac{dy}{dx}$:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}(x+7y-7y)-y = 6x^5(x+7y)^2 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{   6x^5(x+7y)^2 + y}{x}. $$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.However, could you further explain the Factoring bit? Implicit differentiation is ambiguous to me at the moment.

Comment: The implicit differentiation you got right. Your problem is not with calculus. Most people get the chain rule wrong there, and you didn't. In details: 

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x+7y)-(1+7\frac{dy}{dx})(y) = x\frac{dy}{dx}+7y\frac{dy}{dx} - y - 7y\frac{dy}{dx},$$

and these $7y\frac{dy}{dx}$ cancel each other. Instead of distributing everything like I did now, I noticed that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ was a common term, so I factored it out.